# What is this C++ template feature called?

Tags: c++, templates

From within a template function or class, you can call a function on an object of the template parameter T like so:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void call_foo_on_t(T t) {
  t.foo();
}
```

This means you can pass in any type as T that has defines the function `foo()`.

Does this feature/pattern have a "formal" name?

I've tried to search for it but without luck - it's kind of hard to describe in a short enough way for search engines to pick it up.

Comment: I'm not sure it has a name.  This is pretty much the primary purpose of templates.

Comment: *"Does this feature/pattern have a "formal" name?..."* This is a yes/no question.

Comment: Um... "templates"?

Comment: Maybe the closest you will get is "duck typing"?  But even "duck typing" is not a formal name.

Comment: it is called "duck typing"

Comment: @maltebp trying to understand one feature of a lanugage in terms of a different feature in a different lanugage is generally not recommended. Any introduction to templates would have an example like this

Comment: Right, no formal name, but it seem that "duck-typing" is striking pretty close to this. Thanks!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Good point, but that seem like a pretty human thing to do (compare new things to things that we know). And sure, this is shown in introductions to templates, but I don't recall it being given a name (and I know about the feature, I was just curious about the name).

Comment: The closest term that seems appropriate for this is duck typing. Adding that in the answer.

Comment: With a bit more constraints you can change it into "static polymorphism". Read about duck typing/dynamic and static polymorphism here : https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/dynamic-and-static-polymorphism/

Comment: You can actually pass in any type, regardless of whether it has `foo` function or not. There will be a compilation error only when (and if) template body actually gets instantiated at some point.

Comment: [Googles Carbon language](https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang/blob/trunk/docs/design/generics/overview.md) calls their generics "definition checked". Their generics are checked once before instantiation in contrast to C++'s templates which are checked after instantiation for each instantiation. So perhaps this feature (you could also call it a bug) could be called "non-definition checked" or "instantiation checked".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this feature/pattern have a **"formal" name**?

No it doesn't have a formal name in the c++ standard.

The term that is applicable for this is *duck typing*.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I've updated the sentence to *"The term that is applicable for this is *duck typing*."* See if that conveys the message here. You can edit if it doesn't.